# css equivalent of first:child to target first <p> in div with heading and img preceding?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want the first paragraph in the div to be larger text than all following paragraphs, however the paragraph is not the first child of the div.  As written on w3schools I thought the following syntax would work, but it doesn't seem to be:

```
#feature > p:first-child {
    font-size: 22px;
}


#feature p {
    font-size: 16px;
}


<div id="feature">
    <h2>Feature Name</h2>
    <img class="featureimg" src="images/whatever.jpg" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Nam mattis accumsan consequat. Vivamus eu ligula magna. Cras ultrices nisl et justo convallis nec volutpat purus facilisis.Vestibulum eget augue justo, </p>
</div>
```

Obviously I can put the p elements in their own div, but that seems like divitis and i'd like to know if there's a more straightforward way to accomplish this!

http://jsfiddle.net/35yYJ/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The *most* straightforward way to do it is to use CSS3's `:first-of-type`:

```
#feature > p:first-of-type {
    font-size: 22px;
}
```

But browser support for it is poor, so for your case you can try using this CSS2-only selector, assuming the first `p` is always followed by an `h2` and an `img` (from your question title):

```
#feature > h2:first-child + img + p {
    font-size: 22px;
}
```

Comment: If you have many sets of `h2 + img + p [...]` in your `div#feature` and want to target every first `p` that occurs after an `h2 + img`, then `p:first-of-type` won't work. You'll need to use the CSS2 selector, removing the `:first-child` pseudo-class.

Comment: that is amazing! heh. in english i presume it is looking for the first h2 in the feature div then looking that it's followed directly by an img and then a p? I've never seen the '+' before in css

Answer (score 4):

you can target the element above the p, then use "+" adjacent selector to select the p.
so in your case would be:

```
#feature img + p {
    font-size: 22px;
}
```

and it supports from IE7

[Check this working code on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/35yYJ/19/)

Answer (score 1):

`:first-child` does not match because `#feature :first-child` would be the h2 element (and it is not an p tag). `:first-child` is the first child of the parent. You want [:first-of-type](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-of-type-pseudo) from CSS3. But it wont work on IE < 9. Other modern browsers should work though: http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/